# How to generate unique file name for each run in Log4j

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using log4j in my project to use the logs generated for failure analysis. I have a problem in creating a new file each time as it is not working. My requirement is to create a file name in the following format
`Filename_<DDMMYYYY_HHMMSS>` each time when I run my script. but I have tried multiple codes from net and nothing works for me. A file is getting generated in the file folder by using the below xml and scripts using the same file for all the run. Kindly help me to generate a new file each time with the xml below

**XML Used**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j='http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/'>
<appender name="consoleAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
<layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
<!-- For Printing message with date , time & class name also-->
<param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss}] %5p[%c{1}]: %m%n"/>
<!-- For printing message only 
<param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p[%c{1}]: %m%n"/>-->
</layout>
</appender>

<appender name="fileAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
<param name="append" value="false"/>
<param name="file" value="MyApp_%d{ddMMyyyy_HHMMSS}_MyApp.log"/>
<layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
<param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss}%x %-5p[%c{1}]: %m%n"/>
</layout>
 <rollingPolicy class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
      <param name="activeFileName" value="MyApp_%d{ddMMyyyy_HHMMSS}.log"/>
      <param name="fileNamePattern" value="MyApp_%d{ddMMyyyy_HHMMSS}_MyApp.log"/>
      <param name="minIndex" value="0"/>
      <param name="maxIndex" value="5"/>
</rollingPolicy>
</appender>
<root>
<level value="INFO"/>
<appender-ref ref="consoleAppender"/>
<appender-ref ref="fileAppender"/>
</root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

**Error**

> log4j:WARN Continuable parsing error 25 and column 12
>
> log4j:WARN The content of element type "appender" must match "(errorHandler?,param*,rollingPolicy?,triggeringPolicy?,connectionSource?,layout?,filter*,appender-ref*)".
>
> log4j:WARN Unrecognized element rollingPolicy

Sorry for attaching the xml in HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do this by number of ways. But the one which I found is easy to do with the setup in XML. We need to set the variable value by the line below in script,

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss");
Date date = new Date();
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date));   
String dynamicFileName="Logs_"+dateFormat.format(date);
System.setProperty("logfilename", dynamicFileName);
```

With the above code we will be able to setup a dynamic value for the variable `logfilename` in the xml. So when the script creates the object it will create a new file name with the below lines,

```
DOMConfigurator.configure("log4j.xml");
Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Area.class.getName());
Log.error("mulla");
```

**Modified XML Used**

```html
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
    <log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j='http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/'>
     <appender name="consoleAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
      <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
       <!-- For Printing message with date , time & class name also-->
       <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss}] %5p[%c{1}]: %m%n"/>
       <!-- For printing message only 
       <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p[%c{1}]: %m%n"/>-->
      </layout>
     </appender>

     <appender name="fileAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
      <param name="append" value="false"/>
      <param name="file" value="${logfilename}.log"/>
      <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
       <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss}%x %-5p[%c{1}]: %m%n"/>
      </layout>
     </appender>
     <root>
      <level value="INFO"/>
      <appender-ref ref="consoleAppender"/>
      <appender-ref ref="fileAppender"/>
     </root>
    </log4j:configuration>
```

So this code will generate a new file name for each run... Thanks all for the effort to make this code....